# Salesforce Community - Remote Authorization login page cached

Tags: community, oauth2, connected-apps, login

I'm testing out a Connected App with a Salesforce commmunity. I was using a custom login page (Visualforce), and have switched it off to the standard login page.

Viewing the Community directly (https://my-force-domain.com/mycommunity) returns the expected login page; however, when I go through an oauth url (https://my-force-domain.com/mycommunity/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=&redirect_uri=) is still showing the Visualforce page.
Is there something I need to do to flush the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer; in the configured Site for the community, my 404 page was my custom Visualforce login page. When I switched it to the standard Communities Login page, everything worked as expected.